# What is the best suited language to process XML in a web application?

Tags: xml, programming-languages

I'm planning a web application that requires a lot of XML processing: generate XML documents, validate against schemas, generate views from XSLT...
For diferent reasons I've ruled out .NET and J2EE. Also, when I say 'best suited' I'm thinking of syntactic simplicity rather than performance.
Any advantages in using PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails...?

Comment: BTW: apache cocoon could be want you need if you rule in J2EE again ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most languages should use some [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) API -- and/or even if they offer some other choice, using DOM might still be a good solution, as it'll make your code easier to understand by other developpers, as it's a standardized API.

PHP provides XML-manipulation classes based on DOM, that allow to create/read/update XML documents, use XPath and XSLT *(no XSLT 2.0, though)*, validate against Schema, ...

For more informations about XML manipulation in PHP :

- [Document Object Model](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
- And, when you just want to quickly read an XML Document, you might also be interested by [SimpleXML](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Yes, using an standard API is always a good thing. Furthermore, for what I've seen so far most libraries not based on DOM have limited capabilities.
Looks like I will need a different reason to choose among PHP, Python and Ruby.